# docker-compose up" Error "(root) Additional property datastore is not allowed"

Tags: docker-compose

I am trying to run a "docker-compose up" and I keep getting an error code stating "(root) Additional property datastore is not allowed". What am I missing from the Docker-compose.yml file? I have read a few other forms and responses, but it nothing I have tried seems to help. I tried putting a version in the file, and adding service, but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: could you please share your "docker-compose.yml", maybe is a syntax error or a typo, you could use a extension to validate the structure of the file.